# How to install -t?

Tags: ansible

I have the following statement, that I would like to translate into Ansible:

```
$ curl -L https://github.com/drone/drone-cli/releases/latest/download/drone_linux_amd64.tar.gz | tar zx
$ sudo install -t /usr/local/bin drone
```

How to build an Ansible task for it?

I've tried:

```
 - name: Extract droner exec runner into /usr/local/bin
   unarchive:
     src: drone_linux_amd64.tar.gz
     dest: /usr/local/bin/
     mode: "0664"
```

But it does not work as expected.

Comment: Is there an error? This works for me!

Comment: There is no error, but I can not execute `drone` statement in the terminal.

Comment: That is due to the access mode. With `0644` there is no execute permission, change it to `a+x`. Also make sure `/usr/local/bin` is in `$PATH`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`install` command manages the permissions of the file, making sure the execute permissions are added to the file during installation.

`unarchive` just extracts the contents of the archive file to the destination. Set the desired `mode` to the task, in this case to make it executable add the `+x` permission.

```
- name: Extract droner exec runner into /usr/local/bin
   unarchive:
     src: drone_linux_amd64.tar.gz
     dest: /usr/local/bin/
     mode: "a+x"
```

`a+x`, giving execute permission for all expecting the `drone` command will be used across users.

Answer (score 1):

```
- hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
     - name: Get the file from github
       get_url:
            url: "https://github.com/drone/drone-cli/releases/latest/download/drone_linux_amd64.tar.gz"
            dest: /tmp/drone_linux_amd64.tar.gz
     - name: Unarchive the file
       unarchive:
            src: /tmp/drone_linux_amd64.tar.gz
            dest: /tmp
            mode: 0664
     - name: Install
       shell:
            cmd: install -t /usr/local/bin drone
            chdir: /tmp
```

Task 1: Fetching the file form the github with get_url. you can also you shell module. [get_url module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/get_url_module.html)
Task 2: Unarchive the file using unarchive module. [unarchive module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/unarchive_module.html#unarchive-unpacks-an-archive-after-optionally-copying-it-from-the-local-machine) 
Task 3: Install with shell command [shell module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html)

I have unarchive it in the tmp folder. and then installed it.